# Do I need to pass handler prop to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was thinking if I need to pass a handler of textfield/dropdown.

```
const initialFormFields = {
  name: '',
  sample_select: '',
}

const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState(initialFormFields);
```

**Parent Component**

```
  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox"
      ? target.checked
      : target.value;
    setFormFields(formFields => ({...formFields,[target.name]: value}));
  };
```

```
<form onChange={handleInputChange}>
  <ChildComponent 
    name={formFields.name}
    sample_select={formFields.sample_select}
  />
</form>
```

**Child Component**

```
<TextField
  name="name"
  id="name"
  value={props.name}
/>

<TextField
  select
  id="sample_select"
  name="sample_select"
  value={props.sample_select}
>
  <MenuItem value="1">1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="2">2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="3">3</MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

On **TextField** Component it works, but in select component it doesn't trigger the handler

Btw im using Material UI

Comment: I created a sandbox maybe this will make more presentable
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bassi-6c3b0)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "Select" component instead to make it work.
Example:

```
<Select
  value={props.sample_select}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
  >
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

I tried changing "value" attr to "defaultValue", it works but the state doesn't change

Comment: did you change value and onChange parameters to your handlers?

Comment: what do you mean change parameters to handlers? :(

Comment: oh yes itried that, it also work. However, I will do this to all my selects and that would be too handy. That's why I'm trying to call handle on onChange in <form>. See the sandbox link comment in my question, maybe you can visualize what im trying todo. huhu. By the way, checkbox also works, only the select dont trigger the handler

Comment: @eranamarante you can add additional property in useState and by trigger any of the select put current selected value there with select item id, then handle the value and change select what you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

try this in parent:

```
<form onChange={handleInputChange}>
  <ChildComponent 
    name={formFields.name}
    sample_select={formFields.sample_select}
    handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
  />
</form>
```

in ChildComponent:

```
<TextField
  name="name"
  id="name"
  value={props.name}
  onChange={props.handleInputChange} 
/>

<TextField
  select
  id="sample_select"
  name="sample_select"
  value={props.sample_select}
  onChange={props.handleInputChange} 
>
  <MenuItem value="1">1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="2">2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="3">3</MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

Comment: Well that's my first attempt and it works, but i have too many dropdowns and inputs in a form. It's too many to edit that's why i'm trying to make it only one onChange which is in <form> but thanks anyway :)

Comment: maybe react-hook-form is better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Got It! Tried to console.log(event) and saw type of event. It's a **click** event, so I put **onClick** handler and it works! :D